# Linux command - How to remove duplicated lines that contains timestamp

Tags: bash

Is that possible to remove "duplicated" lines. The lines contain timestamp so that I can't easily uniq?

For example:

```
start=12345 end=23456 ERROR=X091
start=12346 end=23457 ERROR=X091
start=12347 end=23458 ERROR=X091
start=12345 end=23456 ERROR=A777
start=12346 end=23457 ERROR=A777
start=12347 end=23458 ERROR=A777
```

Images that there are thousands of lines, and I wanna know how many ERROR type exactly.
Like I want an output:

```
start=12346 end=23457 ERROR=X091
start=12347 end=23458 ERROR=A777
```

Comment: Why not removing the time stamps first, i.e. `cut -f 3-`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the requirement, you need to print out the unique error codes. That should be this easy one liner.

```
$ uniq -f 2  r.txt 
start=12345 end=23456 ERROR=X091
start=12345 end=23456 ERROR=A777
```

> -f => ignore the first 2 fields. The fields are delimited by a blank.

On the other hand, if you are also interested in the count of the number of times each error code occurs, this would help.

```
$ cut -f3 -d' ' r.txt | uniq -c 
   3 ERROR=A777
   3 ERROR=X091
```

For cut:

> -f3 => return the 3rd field.
>   -d => delimiter to use.

For uniq:

> -c => print the count

Comment: Execellet!
Is it ok to set other delimiter like ";" or ","?

Comment: yes. "-d',' set the delimiter to a comma. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are interested in is to know how many error types you have, you can use `sed` to remove the timestamp, then you can run `uniq` on the result.

If you need to work from a command line output, you can pipe it to:

```sh
sed 's/.*\(ERROR=.*\)/\1/' | uniq
```

For instance:

```sh
echo "start=12345 end=23456 ERROR=X091
start=12346 end=23457 ERROR=X091
start=12347 end=23458 ERROR=X091
start=12345 end=23456 ERROR=A777
start=12346 end=23457 ERROR=A777
start=12347 end=23458 ERROR=A777" | sed 's/.*\(ERROR=.*\)/\1/' | uniq
```

Gives:

```sh
ERROR=X091
ERROR=A777
```

If you are working from a file, you can use:

```
sed 's/.*\(ERROR=.*\)/\1/' file | uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

using `awk`

```
awk '{a[$3]=$0;} END { for (i in a) print a[i]}' file.txt
```

Demo :

```
$cat file.txt
start=12345 end=23456 ERROR=X091
start=12346 end=23457 ERROR=X091
start=12347 end=23458 ERROR=X091
start=12345 end=23456 ERROR=A777
start=12346 end=23457 ERROR=A777
start=12347 end=23458 ERROR=A777
$awk -F" " '{a[$3]=$0;} END { for (i in a) print a[i]}' file.txt
start=12347 end=23458 ERROR=X091
start=12347 end=23458 ERROR=A777
$
```

Comment: Yes. Don't know why i added it. :{